# Unable to connect on GitLab.com since 2 days (HTTP, SSH...)

Tags: ssh, gitlab

Let me explain my very strange problem. I have one server (Linux Debian Jessie) which had access to my git repository on gitlab.com

Two days ago, I tried to pull some modifications on this server with a simple git pull. I received an error message :

> ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Connection timed out

Si I have done some tests

**1. TELNET**

To understand why, I have tried a telnet on 22 port = TIMEOUT

**2. IPTABLES**

I checked my iptables to be sure that SSH port was allowed. It is. If I try a telnet on another service for example like github.com, it works. So I'm allowed in OUTPUT on this port.

**3. PING**

I thought a ip translation problem. I have done a ping, I obtain this message :

> PING 104.210.2.228 (104.210.2.228) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   --- 104.210.2.228 ping statistics ---
>   87 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 86534ms

**4. FAIL2BAN**

I use fail2ban, so I have checked if gitlab was in jail address, but it seems not.

So my problem is that I can't reach gitlab.com

If I try from my local machine or from another server, I don't have this problem. It works.

I can't reach gitlab.com only from this server but I don't know why. Maybe someone has an idea which cans be very precious to help me ?

Comment: What is the output of running "ssh -T git@github.com" ?

Comment: On github I obtain this message : Permission denied (publickey). Normal I don't use it on this server. And for gitlab.com, I obtain a timeout

Answer (score 3):

Probably some modification of firewall caused this. For a quick solution use `http` protocol instead of `ssh`. Change your url in the `git` config file to http.

```
git config --local -e
```

change entry of

url = git@gitlab.com:username/repo.git   ,  to

```
url = https://gitlab.com/username/repo.git
```

You need to give your username and password to authenticate yourself while making a push or pull though as it's http based.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this to switch from SSH to HTTPS. My remote is now defined on HTTPS remote git URL but also in this case, it doesn't work, that's why I said in subject (HTTP, SSH...). If I test a CURL on the HTTPS url provide by gitlab.com, I obtain this message : `curl: (7) Failed to connect to gitlab.com port 443: Connexion terminée par expiration du délai d'attente`

Comment: Hmm, sorry but can you check if this works ? "$ ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.gitlab.com" , if that works then you need to update your SSH settings

Comment: ssh -T -p 22 git@gitlab.com ?

Comment: I have also a timeout.

Comment: There is an alternate SSH connection solution in Gitlab which works with port 443, but if that's also blocked in your network then it's very difficult. Check this link: https://about.gitlab.com/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/

Comment: Thanks Tushar for your advices. But how can we explain that simple HTTPS connexion doesn't work also on this server ?